# Navigating the cursor on comment box using keys in Android app with 2 or more line returns the cursor to first line

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

After I have typed 2 or more lines on comment box, when the cursor is not on the first line, navigating the cursor using keys will bring the cursor to first line. This issue doesn't occur on Question or Answer box, only on comment box. This may be a minor bug, since user can reposition the cursor using touch screen, and not all input methods have navigation arrow.

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.12
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 4.4.2
- Keyboard: [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese&hl=en)

Comment: Same on Huawei Y300, 4.1.1, Hacker's Keyboard arrow keys.

Comment: 'Alcatel Pop C9. Latest firmware update. Using latest SwiftKey with no 'flow'.' - [Noein](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/185700/noein)

Comment: Can confirm this is also the case for 4.1.2, Hacker's Keyboard.

Comment: Reproduced on Samsung I9305 (4.4.4), Asus ZE551ML(5.0), Samsung XCover 3 (5.1.1), and Cyanogenmod (4.4).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: the bug seems to reappear on v1.0.85.

---

Seems it's been fixed, or Android version-dependent issue. On Nexus 5 running Marshmallow 6.0 with app v1.0.77 (beta), I can navigate the comment box correctly with arrow keys with Google Japanese IME and Hacker's Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This bug exists in Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.85 with the Multiling O Keyboard