# Android app editing bug

Tags: bug, android-app

When using the text entry form for adding or editing a comment moving the cursor around is impossible. The cursor keeps jumping to the top line of the editing box. It may also affect other boxes too, but that is the one that I recall off hand.

Comment: Please post each bug as a separate question.

Comment: It was hard enough posting one question let alone two;)

Comment: Were you using arrow key on keyboard? Because if you were, then [it's the same bug I have faced before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221928/navigating-the-cursor-on-comment-box-using-keys-in-android-app-with-2-or-more-li), so we need more info, like device model, Android version, SE app version (and Keyboard app, if you're using arrow key)

Comment: Galaxy Tab A SM-T555, Android 5.0.2, SE1.0.77. It does it both with the built in Samsung keyboard app and also with an external bluetooth keyboard. As soon as you have a two-line comment, press the left arrow on the keyboard and you jump to the top line of the comment.