# Arrow button doesn't work when typing comments in Android app with external keyboard

Tags: bug, android-app

How to produce the bug:

1. Connect a Bluetooth or OTG-USB keyboard to an Android device.
2. In SE app, start typing a comment which is 2 lines or longer.
3. While on any line other than the first, try using <kbd>←</kbd> to go back to correct a typo, etc.
4. Instead of taking you just one character back, the button will take you dozens of characters back.

I've reproduced this bug using the latest version (1.0.85) of the app on Samsung I9305 running Android 4.4.4.

I've also reproduced on Asus ZE551ML (Android 5.0).

@IlmariKaronen has reproduced on Samsung XCover 3 (Android 5.1.1)

@meatball has reproduced on the Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.2).

Android devices with hard keyboards are becoming more and more common. Remix OS is gaining ground. Android apps are coming to Chrome OS. Therefore, this bug should be given priority to fix. Also, it should be relatively easy to fix. I have never seen any other Android app with this type of bug.

Comment: Reproduced with Samsung XCover 3 / Android 5.1.1 and a Microsoft Wedge bluetooth keyboard. Curiously, changing the screen orientation (regardless of what it originally was) seems to make the bug disappear, and it doesn't reappear when I rotate the device back again. Canceling the comment by pressing the back button and then trying to post a new comment (even with just the same content copy-pasted in) does re-trigger it.

Comment: ... On the other hand, while rotating the screen while typing a comment seems to fix this bug, it also seems to trigger another bug that breaks the "post" button, making the comment impossible to submit. :( I had to use copy+paste to post the previous comment.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, I got the exact same behavior as you when I tried the rotation thing, including the broken "post" button. And that seems to be unrelated to the keyboard thing, as rotating the screen breaks the post button even without any external keyboard. Oo

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Since the rotation thing is a separate issue I've posted it [as a separate question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280520/321647)

Comment: Same bug does not occur on iOS devices.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks for checking, could you do [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280520/321647) too?

Comment: Seems related/dupe of [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221928/navigating-the-cursor-on-comment-box-using-keys-in-android-app-with-2-or-more-li). SE app had a weird bug with arrow keys for navigation in the first place (whether it's soft/physical keyboard).

Comment: @meatball Yeah, looks like a dupe!

Comment: Any reason you ruined your post?

Comment: @ShadowWizard What do you mean?

Comment: @Fiksdal you did not edit?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but what do you mean by "ruin"?

Comment: You really didn't notice the numerous typos, gibberish words and bad formatting?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No. I'm not that familiar with formatting standards, and English is only my second language. Feel free to do a cleanup of this post. Or tell me in comments what I can improve.

Comment: I think Shadow Wizard referred to [this revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/280502/5), and if I should guess the reason, you're probably (pocket-typing accidentally?) editing this post from the app. No worries, it has been fixed.

Comment: @meatball is correct, and if you still don't know what I'm talking about: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UUY61.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wow! Yeah, I have no idea how I was able to pull that off... LOL. Thanks for fixing.