# Rotating screen breaks "Post" button for comments in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

How to reproduce bug:

1. Start typing a comment.
2. Rotate the screen orientation of your device.
3. Try clicking the "POST" button.
4. Nothing will happen.

I've reproduced using the the latest version (1.0.85) of the app on Samsung I9305 running Android 4.4.4

And Asus ZE551ML (5.0).

@IlmariKaronen [has reproduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280502/arrow-button-doesnt-work-when-typing-comments-in-android-app-with-external-keyb?noredirect=1#comment910840_280502) on Samsung XCover 3 (5.1.1).

@JonasCz has reproduced this on Cyanogenmod (4.4).

@meatball has reproduced this on Nexus 5 (6.0.1).

Comment: iOS doesn't have this one either.